# Bittrex API rate limit

Tags: api, bittrex

Does Bittrex have a limit on how many requests I can do? I cannot find that info in their documentation.

I only find their [Announcement](https://bittrex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202673194-The-taming-of-the-Bots-Part-II) from 2014 which says:

> Api requests will be throttled based on data intensity and resource
>   utilization, calls will be eligible for throttling if they exceed:
>
> Low:  1 request per second
>
> Medium: 1 request per 10 seconds
>
> High: 1 request per 30 seconds
>
> The API documentation will be updated shorty to
>   reflect the intensity level of each call. These changes are still in
>   draft and we're looking for community feedback.

But it doesn't look like they put these limits live, and their API documentation doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: Have you tried asking the Bittrex support? If you do and they reply, please answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has been asked in the #api-developers channel of the [Bittrex Slack Group](https://bittrex.slack.com/) a few times.

Here's the important fragment of the discussion with somewhat an answer to our question.

> July 2nd, 2017

```
Some user:
seriously guys.. the rate limit.. what is it..

bittrex-bill:
It varies by API call.
If you hit the limit, you are abusing it. If you hit the limit a lot, you risk getting banned :)
I dont have a clearer answer for you right now

Some user:
Is greater than 1 minute consistently 24/7 within an acceptable use?

bittrex-bill:
yes
```

That's it! I personally wish they would update the API docs with a clear and hard limitation, but for now, when we're writing code that is long-running, and executes in a loop, we should try to cap the requests around 1 request per minute per API method.

Answer (score 3):

@reboltof mentions in [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59316/trading-bot-what-is-the-maximum-load-an-exchange-server-can-take) that they got banned for a week for spamming the API. The email @reboltof received from Bittrex when the ban was lifted said to limit API calls to 1 request per second.

Comment: I think it was mentioned here: https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002152712-Bittrex-Beta-API-Documentation. But page is now not accessible.

Comment: Found the original post via Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180626130102/https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002152712-Bittrex-Beta-API-Documentation

Comment: That is what the docs say as well for the API v3 (60 calls per minute). But they don't distinguish between calls for different user accounts that originate from the same IP. Binance does make this distinction, so it is much easier to implement code to temper the call rates.

Answer (score 0):

60 API calls per minute

> The Bittrex API employs call limits on all endpoints to ensure the efficiency and availability of the platform for all customers. In general, API users are permitted to make a maximum of 60 API calls per minute. Calls after the limit will fail, with the limit resetting at the start of the next minute.

https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3#topic-Best-Practices