# Bittrex: What Error Do You Receive for Spamming the API?

Tags: bittrex

I have a script which queries the Bittrex API pretty frequently (it makes an order after the previous order has filled).

[This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53778/bittrex-api-rate-limit) asks about the rate limits. Therein, it is mentioned that Bittrex is rather dodgy about the rate limits, and they could change over time.

I want to know what the error/warning response for spamming the API is so I can slow down my requests adaptively (and therefore, not need to edit my script if they change the rate limit in the future).

Does anyone know what the error/warning response for spamming the API is?

Comment: If you spam it enough you probably get a loic.

Comment: What does loic mean?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear from Bittrex what error message is received when you encounter a limit. They just say that the request will fail. According the [latest information from Bittrex](https://github.com/Bittrex/beta) Accounts can query the API up to 60-times a minute, once per second.

That said, there is a "success" flag returned for every request to the Bittrex API. I would imagine that this would be "false" and there would be some sort of message explaining the error. Maybe just look for false?

Comment: The query rate info is useful; it's good they added that. I'm not sure if the success flag idea would work in practice. I imagine querying an order that gets removed from the books would also return "false."